# Commas inside numbers from range input

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to make this grafic work, but I'm some kind of a new in this whole thing so I have a few things that I can't get to work.

My first problem it's with the commas. So if you drag on the first range and you get a value like 1000000 i want it to appear like 1,000,000. Or any other number.

I've tryied something, but it doesn't look to work all the time.

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

jQuery('#slider1out').each(function () {
    var v_pound = jQuery(this).html();
    v_pound = numberWithCommas(v_pound);

    jQuery(this).html(v_pound);

});
```

These is the fiddle (normally when you drag the first range and get a value, an answer should appear at the bottom, but it doesn't appear on fiddle, don't know why): https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/

If you can help me it will be much appreciated !
Thanks and have a great week-end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your fiddle js load type to `no wrap - in <body>` your code appears to be working (this will get your jsfiddle working).

You have most of the code in the right place to do what you're after. To make the output work it is based off the `form` elements `oninput` event setting the value of the `output` element. We can leverage this event to call the `numberWithCommas` function.

This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Expose the `numberWithCommas` function to the global scope, and call it in the inline form `oninput` attribute. ie. `oninput="level.value = numberWithCommas(flevel.valueAsNumber)"` **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/1/)**
2. More preferable in my opinion, as custom global scoped functions have potential to be overwritten. Hook into the `input` event on the form, and execute our own function to replace the html of the `output` element. (if you choose this method, i would suggest saving your `$('#slider1out')` and `$('#flying1')` lookups to variables outside of the input function to reduce DOM lookups, code provided in below format for brevity) **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/2/)**

   ```
   $(function() {

       function numberWithCommas(x) {
           return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       }

       $('#calculationForm').on('input', function(){
           $('#slider1out').html(numberWithCommas($('#flying1').val()));
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only it works like a charm, but i've understand what you did :D
One question, if you don't mind. I saw you've put on #flying1 a default value 80,000, that appears and make the calculation down on the "roundslider". I did want to do that, but how can I make that 80k value appear right of the range slider. So when the page first appears slider 1 has a value of 80,000 and the answer down is 12,000. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the same way as option two. You can just set the .html() property of it to '80,000' :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for stupid questions, I'm still learning. Thanks again !!